# Customized keyboard shorcuts with gnome-shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell

I would like to customize some keystrokes in gnome-shell and I have two problems:

1. I would like to have `Shift+Enter` launch Emacs but gnome-shell doesn't want me to use this shortcut. How can I overpass it and use it anyway?
2. I have a multimedia wheel which works out of the box and allows me to change the volume. However, I don't like it and want to use instead some keystrokes. I want to use `Ctrl+PageUp` and `Ctrl+PageDown` to increase and decrease the volume. I tried to use `amixer "-q set Master 5%- unmute"` and `amixer "-q set Master 5%+ unmute"` which work for a terminal (without a notification which is a little issue). I can add the two shortcuts in gnome-settings interface but they will not work.
3. In the same kind of shortcut, I would like to replace "next" and "previous" button by "mpc next" and "mpc prev". I tried to do this but when I hit "replace", nothing happens and the default shortcut stays the same...

Any idea? Is there another way to set the shortcuts than the gnome-settings interface (I did look in dconf-editor without luck)?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't use Gnome and I don't know the answer. There are a bunch of utilities for dealing with keyboards and keyboard input. The problem is that Gnome may see things before they do. Here's a laundry list of things that might help: xmodmap xdotool xset xkb AutoKey. See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg and https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/769644-hacking-your-linux-keyboard-with-xkb
 These are just directions to look in.

Comment: Nobody answered, because these are three separate questions that needs a lot of time to investigate. Better split them into separate ones.